# onClick event + jquery to modify a class css style in a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, class

I have been looking around for a while, but i couldn't find a proper solution, so I registered and this is the first question i'm posting. I hope you can help me:

I'm trying to create a set of five buttons (divs) with onClick event that show five diferent divs. I have created an inline code for each button and it works, but im trying to create an external function to perform the task just setting the div clicked (that will display a yellow border) and the div that should be displayed.

A scheme of the code im trying to write is:

HTML:

```
<div id="button1" class="button" onClick="choose(this,'c1')"></div>
<div id="button2" class="button" onClick="choose(this,'c2')"></div>
<div id="button3" class="button" onClick="choose(this,'c3')"></div>
<div id="button4" class="button" onClick="choose(this,'c4')"></div>
<div id="button5" class="button" onClick="choose(this,'c5')"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<div class="c4"></div>
<div class="c5"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT-JQUERY:

```
function choose(button,card) {
$( "#button1" ).css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
$( "#button2" ).css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
$( "#button3" ).css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
$( "#button4" ).css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
$( "#button5" ).css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
$( "div.c1" ).hide();
$( "div.c2" ).hide();
$( "div.c3" ).hide();
$( "div.c4" ).hide();
$( "div.c5" ).hide();
$( button ).css("border-color", "#FFCC00");
$( div.card ).show();
}
```

The border (selector) task works fine and changes the border color of the div clicked, but I cant find a way to take the class name that should be shown into the jquery function, it should be one of the c1, c2, c3, c4 or c5. Can someone help me with this?

Best overall solution http://jsbin.com/UXElode/4/edit thanks to @Roko C. Buljan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$("." + card).show();
```

Comment: Was the solution! Thank you very much! I cant still vote up, but please if someone sees this, upvote this solution

Comment: @AntonioValero You can surely choose this answer as "accepted answer". By clicking on the "check mark" below the votes. But you should perhaps follow the other's approaches of following your idea of "separating the tasks".

Answer (score 2):

How about having only this:

```
<div id="button1" class="button"></div>
<div id="button2" class="button"></div>
<div id="button3" class="button"></div>
<div id="button4" class="button"></div>
<div id="button5" class="button"></div>
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
<div class="c4"></div>
<div class="c5"></div>
```

and this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $('.button').css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
     $( this ).css("border-color", "#FFCC00");
     var n = this.id.split('n')[1];
     $('.c'+ n).show();
});
```

To extract the number out of the clicked ID element you can also do:

```
     var n = this.id.match(/\d+/g);
```

**[and a live demo](http://jsbin.com/UXElode/2/edit)**

Comment: Thank you, I had solved it inline coded and it works as well! Those were not the real names of the classes and ids, they are not numeric. i changed them just to post the example. I wanted to know how to include a class name in a function arguments, but thank you too!

Comment: And thanks for the demo, i just knew jsfiddle! Real thanks for the interest!

Comment: This one is missing the line that hides the non-active divs, but easy to code!

Comment: @AntonioValero this one can be done in even less lines of code. The part that hides all the other elements was intentionally left out cause was not requested in the Question as far as I can see. But here you go with an example http://jsbin.com/UXElode/4/edit Look also at how simplified is the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
<div id="button1" class="button"></div>
<div id="button2" class="button"></div>
<div id="button3" class="button"></div>
<div id="button4" class="button"></div>
<div id="button5" class="button"></div>
<div class="c button1"></div>
<div class="c button2"></div>
<div class="c button3"></div>
<div class="c button4"></div>
<div class="c button5"></div>
```

With this Javascript:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".button").css("border-color", "#F1F1F1");
  $(".c").hide();
  $( this ).css("border-color", "#FFCC00");
  $( "."+this.id ).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. I had never used double classes, but will read about them a bit!

Answer (score 0):

How About coding it like this?

**HTML**

```
<form id="btun">
    <div id="c1" style="background-color:#F1F1F1">btn 1</div>
    <div id="c2" style="background-color:#F1F1F1">btn 2</div>
    <div id="c3" style="background-color:#F1F1F1">btn 3</div>
     <div id="c4" style="background-color:#F1F1F1">btn 4</div>
    <div id="c5" style="background-color:#F1F1F1">btn 5</div>
</form>
<form id="array">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <div class="c3">c3</div>
    <div class="c4">c4</div>
    <div class="c5">c5</div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript (w/JQuery)**

```
$('#btun div').click(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + a).hide();
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jgvm/1/)

Comment: This one hides divs one by one, I was trying to show one, and hide the others! :)

Comment: well make it hidden by default a change `.hide();` to `.show();`